# Twisted calibrations and sufficient conditions on homology of sub-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, differential-topology

I think my question is somehow easy to solve, but I'm not very familiar with algebraic topology, so I'm not able to figure out the solution for myself. I'm working on a problem in metric geometry and to this end I'm using calibration theory for a minimality statement. The following fact is crucial for calibration theory:

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold and $\omega$ a closed differential $k$-form. By Stokes' theorem we conclude that for compact, oriented $\mathbb{R}$-homologous sub-manifolds $N^k$ and $N'^k$ it holds
$$
\int_N\omega=\int_{N'}\omega.
$$
I was wondering if this can be extended somehow to non-orientable sub-manifolds. The obvious thing to do is to use twisted $k$-forms instead of ordinary $k$-forms, i.e. $k$-forms with values in the orientation bundle $Or_M$. Those can be integrated over $k$-dimensional sub-manifolds, orientable or not.

The corresponding cohomology is the de Rham cohomology $H^*(M;Or_M)$, which is equivalent to the singular cohomology $H^*(M;\mathbb{R}^w)$ twisted by the orientation character $w: \pi_1M \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ of $M$. The integration of a closed twisted form $\omega\in\Omega(M;Or_M)$ over a sub-manifold $N^k$ then corresponds to the cap product $[\omega]\smallfrown[N]$ with the twisted fundamental class $[N]\in H_k(N;\mathbb{R}^w)\cong \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\mathbb{R}^w$-homologous sub-manifolds yield the same integral.

Another approach (see T. Murdoch, "Twisted Calibrations"), is to identify twisted forms with "odd forms" on the orientable double cover $\hat M$ (as de Rham did), i.e. with the subspace $\Omega^*_-(M)$ given by the forms which are invariant under sheet-interchange. Sub-manifolds of $M$ do not canonically induce sub-manifolds of $\hat M$, since one has two possibilities to identify $\hat N$ with $\hat M|_N$. Fix such an isomorphism as an "$Or_M$-orientation" then, there is a canonical way to orient $\partial N$, similar to the case for orientable manifolds. In this sense, it holds 
$$
\int_N d\omega = \int_{\partial N} \omega, \qquad \forall \omega \in \Omega^{k-1}(M;Or_M)
$$
what can be seen by Stokes' theorem on $\hat M$ for $\hat N$ and $\hat{\partial N}=\partial\hat N$. Denote the opposite orientation by $-N$, then
$$
\int_N\omega - \int_{N'}\omega = \int_{N\sqcup-N'}\omega.
$$
The latter integral would vanish for a closed twisted form, if $N\sqcup-N'=\partial S$ for an $Or_M$-oriented $(k+1)$-dimensional sub-manifold $S$ (in the sense of cobordism?).

I somehow expect that both approaches are equivalent. Nevertheless I'm not satisfied, since  I am interested in some sort of sufficient conditions for the sub-manifolds $N$ and $N'$, i.e to be $\mathbb{R}^w$-homologous or "cobordant". E.g. does it hold for $\mathbb{Z}_2$-homologous sub-manifolds?

P.S.: Although I'm very interested in general conditions, I work in the special case that $M$ is a vector space and $k=2$.

Comment: A few comments. In order for a closed submanifold $N^k\subseteq M$ to represent a class $[N]\in H_k(M;\mathbb{R}^{w(M)})$, you need to make some choices, namely: 1) a choice of fundamental class $[N]\in H_k(N;\mathbb{R}^{w(N)})\cong\mathbb{R}$, and 2) a choice of orientation of the normal bundle. In particular, if the normal bundle is not orientable then $N$ does not represent such a class.

Comment: Secondly, I think the answer to your question in the second-to-last paragraph is no. For example, if $N$ is a submanifold with trivial normal bundle, we can obtain a submanifold $3N$ which is $3$ disjointly embedded copies of $N$ (just shift it along some normal vector field). Then $N$ and $3N$ are $\mathbb{Z}/2$-homologous, but may not be $\mathbb{R}^{w(M)}$-homologous (but as I said above, this depends on choices made).

Comment: I see your point - I missed somehow to think about the representation of $[N]$ in $M$. It seems to me that homology theory is not that useful for the integration of twisted forms as it is for ordinary forms. By this, I also have the feeling, that the lifting of sub-manifolds to the orientable double cover is in general not possible.